# Auto fix the width of a floating div to image size

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-float, width

I'm wondering if there is a way to force a floated div that contains an image and some text to not stretch beyond the width of the image (rather than the text) and so force the text to wrap at that width.

```html
<div>
   <img src="some.jpg">
   <p>Some descriptive text here..</p>
</div>
```

All is well when the text string takes less room than the width of the image. But when there's more text the default is to let the div expand without wrapping the text.

The obvious solution is to define the the width of the div as the same as the image. However as I have about 50 pages like this and every image is a different size and orientation I'd like to find a way that avoids coding each one separately.

I'd prefer a CSS solution if possible but otherwise JS. The site is static so can't use a server side solution.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is one method for doing this.

```css
div {
  display: inline-block;
}

p {
  word-break: break-all;
  min-width: 100%;
  width: min-content;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/fd/ComaAberrationSample.jpg">
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy </p>
</div>
```

Comment: Awesome. Thanks so much. `flex: 1` doesn't seem necessary from my quick tries. And presumably if it is then the div should be `display: inline-flex` ?

Comment: Sorry that was mistakenly added. I edited the answer